# Flutter: How to add Music node (wave) with custom music player

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

How can I implement a real-time waveform analyzer in Flutter for a custom music player?

The waveform should dynamically adjust based on the music beats as the song is played, aiding in music learning by visually representing.

Right now, I am not implemented anything for this & just picked this package [`audio_waveforms`](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_waveforms) to achieve expected result.

I want some expert advice from community to build realtime-wave generator for songs.

Please recommded any other package/library if exist or provide me some suggestions.